# Gravatar returns wrong file extension

Tags: php, gravatar

I'm trying to get JPG images from Gravatar by adding .jpg at the end of the hash, like this:
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000.jpg?d=wavatar&f=y

However, if I save it to the disk like this:

```
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000.jpg?d=wavatar&f=y'));
```

Or if I save it directly from the browser to my computer I notice that the file is in fact a PNG image.

Why is that?
Am I missing something?

Thks!

Comment: Oh... Okay, that's what totally the API gave. So, why not use gd to convert it into JPG?

Answer (score 1):

That link will give you png file even you have jpg at the end. If you want a jpeg image, try this in your php.

```
echo '<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'. md5(strtolower("myemail@gmail.com")).'"
class="img-circle" alt="User Image">';
```

Code at [phponline](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b46a90eb06edcf110c40911fd6038bbe70c0b014) and download [this jpeg image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a316f002a5d080a613dce89a4ad8f9a9).